# AdMob MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID") deprecated alternative

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I was following the [firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#add-app-id-to-androidmanifest) to enable ads in a android app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
}
```

The **initialize** method seems to be deprecated but the official guide recommends to use it.
Is there any alternative that I shall use to initialize Ads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method instead: [`initialize(Context, OnInitializationCompleteListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#initialize(android.content.Context,%20com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener))

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

     }
});
```

Comment: Don't we need to pass the admod app id uisng this approach?